# Internet Explorer ::How to see the " Don't let this page create more messages" check box

Tags: security, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

In IE11 Contrary to the questions posted. Please help me to get this checkbox.

At the moment, I am not able to see the check box with message, please help to get it back.
I tried several security setting of IE, but not fruitful till now

[image]

Comment: If the site is added to the trusted site then just for testing purposes try to remove it from that list and see whether you again start getting this checkbox. I try to check for any specific option to enable it but I did not get any option for it.